# Was ist die Herkunft von „lohnenswert“?

Tags: meaning, etymology

So weit ich weiß, wird *lohnenswert* im Sinne von *lohnend* verwendet. Die Struktur des Wortes scheint aber zu implizieren, dass es lohnenswert ist, wenn es wert ist, dass jemand es (be-? ent-?)lohnt. Wie ist das Wort zu seiner Bedeutung gekommen?

Comment: lohnenswert = lohnbringend = nutzbringend = es lohnt sich es zu tun?

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lohnenswert

Comment: @suemi Basis einer Antwort ;)

Answer (score 5):

Das Schema kennt man von vergleichbaren Wörtern wie *liebenswert*. Wenn jemand *liebenswert* ist, so muss man ihn/sie einfach lieb haben. Er/Sie ist es wert zu lieben. Dabei ist es ein Kompositum aus Nomen + Adjektiv.

Bei *lohnenswert* liegt eine Analogie vor. Das Kompositum ist gleichermaßen gebildet und legt nahe, dass etwas wert ist zu lohnen. Ich vermute, dass genau daher die Frage rührt?!

Diese Bedeutung listet Wiktionary übrigens tatsächlich auf:

> [2] selten: so geartet, dass es belohnt werden sollte

Leider haben weder DWDS noch das Grimmesche Wörterbuch direkt dazu Einträge, aber unter *lohnen* im [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL06653#XGL06653) findet man Folgendes:

> d) mit dem acc. der sache, die der grund des lohnens ist, und persönlichem dativ, einem etwas lohnen: werdet erst männer, dann werdet ihr weiber finden, die euren werth euch lohnen. Klinger 1, 485;
>
> ihm ward .. schon oft die schönste that 
>   durch worte nur gelohnt. 
>   Gotter 1, 168;
>
> dasz die unsterblichen dir diese wohlthat lohnen! 2, 43;
>
> wie lohn ich dir so viele schöne thaten! 
>   Gökingk 3, 118;

An dieser Stelle muss ich die sicheren Gewässer verlassen und spekulieren, aber es liegt nahe, dass die Komposition sich ursprünglich tatsächlich darauf bezog, dass etwas wert ist zu lohnen. Und dass dann mit der Zeit Dinge als *lohnenswert* bezeichnet wurden, wenn abzusehen war, dass die "Tat" wert sein würde zu lohnen.

---

Ich kann noch eine zweite Sichtweise hinzufügen, wobei ich hierzu keinerlei Referenzen liefern kann.
Ich hab mir überlegt, welche Art Kompositum vorliegt. Ich bin zum Entschluss gekommen, dass es ein Determinativkompositum ist. Das bedeutet, dass der erste Teil den zweiten näher bestimmt.

Nehmen wir nochmals *liebenswert*. Der Kern ist also "wert" und eine liebenswerte Person, ist also eine Person, die es "wert" ist. Und zwar "zu lieben wert".
In Analogie dazu ist eine lohnenswerte Sache, eine Sache, die es "wert" ist. Und zwar "zu lohnen wert".

Ob die Liebe oder der Lohn am Ende herausspringt, bleibt offen.

Comment: Das genannte Schema verstehe ich, und danach müsste die Bedeutung die sein, die nur selten gemeint ist. Ist die Benutzung des Wortes als „lohnend“ Deiner Meinung nach dann zumindest ursprünglich schlicht nachlässig?

Comment: @CarstenS Wie erwähnt, spekuliere ich hier weitesgehend. Ich habe ja keinerlei Referenzen, wann, wer und warum das Wort so zum ersten Mal verwendet hat. Ich sehe aber keine Nachlässigkeit hier. Hier liegt denke ich einfach ein natürlicher Wandel des Wortes vor (wie es vielen Wörtern ergangen ist). Zumal mein zweiter Ansatz sogar eine Sichtweise erlaubt, wo unsere primäre Bedeutung sogar sozusagen die "Richtige" ist.

Comment: gibt es so etwas wie das Gegenteil von lohnenswert?

Answer (score 3):

Danke @Suemi für den Link zu Wiktionary!

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lohnenswert) nennt zwei mögliche Ursprünge des Wortes *lohnenswert*:

> Je nach Interpretation von **wert** als Suffixoid oder als Lexem: Ableitung oder Kompositum mit dem substantivierten Infinitiv **lohnen** und dem Fugenelement **-s**

Die Verknüpfung von **Wert** und **(sich) lohnen** habe ich dabei als Muttersprachler immer so verstanden, dass etwas **wert ist** **entlohnt zu werden**. Die Synonyme [lohnend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lohnenswert)(=[Mühen und Kosten rechtfertigend](http://duden.de/rechtschreibung/lohnend)) und [nutzbringend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lohnenswert) bestätigen meiner Meinung nach auch diese Herleitung. Die Deutung erschien mir dabei immer so selbstverständlich, dass ich den Sinn nie hinterfragt habe.

> Das Wort wurde im späten 20. Jahrhundert (bis dahin in Wörterbüchern unbekannt) als **Kofferwort gebildet aus lohnend und
>   lobenswert** und hat seitdem eine gewisse Verbreitung gefunden.

Die zweite Theorie, dass es ein [Kofferwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteauwort), das heißt eine Wortkreuzung aus zwei anderen Wörtern ist, klingt auch erstmal logisch, ist allerdings nur eine Theorie und hat auf Wiktionary keine Quellenangabe.

Comment: Ich glaube, auch diese Antwort zielt an der eigentlichen Frage vorbei. Das Kompositum ist offensichtlich und OP durchaus bekannt. Die Theorie mit dem Kofferwort ist in meinen Augen übrigens Schwachsinn, hilft aber im Bezug zur eigentlichen Frage auch nicht weiter.

Comment: Danke. Die Kofferworttheorie würde meinen ersten Impuls, das Wort als Fehler zu betrachten, rechtfertigen. Leider ist sie bisher nur Spekulation. Die erste Variante, das Wort als „lohnendwertig“ zu interpretieren, überzeugt mich nicht.

Comment: @Em1, ich glaube, ich habe die Frage vorhin nicht richtig verstanden (und bin zu sehr nach dem Titel gegangen). Ich habe meine Antwort ein wenig ergänzt/umformuliert.

Comment: Die Wörter "lohnend" und "nutzbringend" besagen aber doch nicht, dass etwas "wert ist belohnt zu werden", sondern nur, dass es "sich lohnt, etwas zu tun, weil man darauf Profit schlägt". Entsprechend ist eine "lohnenswerte Aufgabe" eine Aufgabe, die es sich lohnt zu tun, weil ich Vorteile daraus habe und weniger eine Aufgabe, die es wert ist belohnt zu werden. Insofern bin ich überrascht, dass deine natürliche Auffassung "wert ist belohnt zu werden" ist, da ich denke, dass die wenigsten die von Wiktionary als selten deklarierte (und im Duden gar nicht gelistete) sekundäre Meinung kennen/sehen.

Comment: Ich verstehe das Problem nicht ganz @Em1. "Lohnend" bedeutet "Mühen und Kosten rechtfertigend" (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lohnend), dass heißt, dass Etwas, das ich tue, einen Wert hat, der eine Gegenleistung (z.B. Lohn/Gehalt) rechtfertigt. Etwas ist damit wert belohnt zu werden. Ist es verständlich, wenn ich entlohnt statt belohnt schreibe?